# SVG border animation doesn't work correctly in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an issue with Safari when I test the below code, however the animation works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="690" y2="0"></line>
        <line class="left" x1="0" y1="230" x2="0" y2="-400"></line>
        <line class="bottom" x1="230" y1="60" x2="-460" y2="60"></line>
        <line class="right" x1="230" y1="0" x2="230" y2="690"></line>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 230px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
div svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

div svg line {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dasharray: 230;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    transition: transform .6s;
}
div:hover svg line.top {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-460px);
    transform: translateX(-460px);
}
div:hover svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(460px);
    transform: translateX(460px);
}
div:hover svg line.left {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(330px);
    transform: translateY(330px);
}
div:hover svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-460px);
    transform: translateY(-460px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4frf6oa/2/

And here's how it looks while mousemove in Chrome and Safari.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Safari]

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(415px);
        transform: translateX(460px);
```

You specify different pixel values for `-webkit-transform` and `transform`. The reason why Safari looks weird is because it uses the `-webkit-transform` definition, whereas most other browsers use the `transform` definition. To fix this, you just need to change the webkit one to also be `460px`.

Comment: @SamLoya You updated your code to be `415px` - please try `460px` and see if it solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The error still exist, please help. jsfiddle.net/e4frf6oa/2